# check if a sub-srting is present in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some help in resolving a problem using python and pandas for dataframe.

I have 2 columns namely 'data' and 'full_data' if any subset of 'data' is present in 'full_data' then I need the matched subset value in new column called 'new_finding'

I need output as wiht a new column 'new_finding:

| data | full_data | new_finding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123456789 | [123456] |
| 345643 | 456432345876 | [456,345,43] |

Comment: Can you share what have u tried so far

Comment: I have tried to use df['new_finding'].str.contains() but it gives whether substring is present or not but I need the value of the substring

Comment: Your spec is not sufficient.  In the second line, why wouldn't you have `[3, 4, 5, 6, 34, 45, 56, 345, 456, 43]"?  In any case, you don't be able to do this with a single command.  You'll have to do it line by line, and the string matching won't be easy.  A regex won't do it.

Comment: I doubt whether the information is useful if even only one digit match is also extracted.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts even those values can be added in the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
import re
from itertools import permutations

def combs(letters):
    for n in range(1, len(letters)+1):
        yield from map(''.join, permutations(letters, n))
df['new_finding'] = df.apply(lambda x: ([re.findall(comb,str(x['full_data'])) for comb in combs(str(x['data']))]),axis=1)
df['new_finding'] = df['new_finding'].apply(lambda row:[x for x in row if x != []])
df['new_finding'] = df['new_finding'].apply(lambda row:[list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in row)])
df['new_finding'] = df['new_finding'].apply(lambda row:[item[0] for item in row])
df
```

**Output**

```
data    full_data   new_finding
123456  123456789   [45, 1234, 6, 23, 123456, 4, 123, 3456, 12, 5, 3, 12345, 23456, 1, 56, 2345, 234, 345, 2, 34, 456]
345643  456432345876    [345, 5, 564, 45, 45643, 6, 4, 34, 643, 43, 56, 4564, 5643, 456, 3, 64]
```

Comment: @jezrael Sorry for what? I do not understand.

Comment: @jezrael don't worry about it. It is water under the bridge. We are here to learn & you have helped me learn a lot, so, I don't mind a few harsh words for you to help me improve.